# How can I retrieve an object from a generic list based on the value of two of that object's members?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

I can retrieve an object from a generic list of that object like so:

```
return _itemTotalsAcrossMonthsList.Find(s => s.ItemDescription == desc);
```

But how can I retrieve an object from a generic list when I need to search on multiple object member values (in my case two). I start off with this:

```
ItemsForMonthYear ifmy;
. . .
ifmy = _itemsForMonthYearList.Find(s => s.ItemDescription == itemDesc);
```

...but I need to also search based on the value in monthYr. I hoped it would be something obvious like this:

```
ifmy = _itemsForMonthYearList.Find(s => s.ItemDescription == itemDesc, t => t.monthYr == monYr);
```

Do I need to do something like:

```
ifmy = from _itemsForMonthYearList.
       Where (ItemDescription == itemDesc) && (monthYr == monYr).
       Select(*);
```

? The latter doesn't work either, but which direction is the right one, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The predicate in here simply resolves to a `bool` to determine whether something matches or not:

```
Find(s => s.ItemDescription == itemDesc)
```

So anything which resolves to a `bool` would have the same effect:

```
Find(s => s.ItemDescription == itemDesc && s.monthYr == monYr)
```